# How to run headless chromium browser in AWS lambda using selenium and java without docker?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-linux-2

unable to run chromium on traditional aws lambda. also i dont want to use docker.

For instance, I have uploaded the compiled binaries of the chrome driver and headless chromium into a lambda layer and have used system.setProperties in my code also have set the binaries for headless chromium but getting this error in lambda logs:

```
/opt/lib/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.  Host info: host: '169.254.145.9', ip: '169.254.145.9': org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException
```

can any body help me with this.

Comment: Compiled binaries for what platform?  I've not done what you're trying to do but Lambda's run in 64 bit Linux environments and I don't know how they handle 32 bits.

Comment: Amazon linux 2, i want to run selenium and headless chrome on aws lambda to execute ui test suites.

Comment: I don't see a AWS Linux 2 package on the [downloads page](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/linux/chromium_packages.md) and you appear to be using a 32 bit driver.  Again, what did you package?